# How can I create a RoI pooling layer in tensorlfow/keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, roi

I've programmed a VGG16 based CNN and now I want to create a faster R-CNN from it. In all the architecture photos I've seen it is needed to have a RoI pooling layer but I don't know how to implement one. Is there an function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras/Tensorflow does not provide an implementation of ROI Pooling Layer, so you need to code it yourself.

You can have code reference from this [repository](https://github.com/kbardool/keras-frcnn/blob/master/keras_frcnn/RoiPoolingConv.py)